# How can I get all defined classes?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to get the list of all defined classes. I'm looking for a code like this:

```ruby
Class.instances.each do |klass|
  puts klass.name
end
```

If there is no way to do this. It is possible to define a class A such that its descendants are registered in it? For example in this way:

```ruby
class A
  ...
end

class B < A
end

class C < B
end

A.descendants   # => [B, C]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
p ObjectSpace.each_object(Class){|ob| p ob}
```

Comment: Your first solution won’t work, as `constants` returns an array of symbols, not the actual constants.

Comment: I know what `constants` does, but you don’t seem to. `Object.constants.grep(Class).empty? #=> true`, thus your `each` is useless.

Comment: `ob` will *never* be an instance of Class. This means that you include things that are not classes in your list since you never filter them. I’m not trying to be rude, but you’re pointing me to documentation that shows that what you’re doing doesn’t work as you expect.

Comment: Just because there’s output doesn’t mean it’s correct… which it’s not.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall you are correct! updated.

Answer (score 7):

The ObjectSpace can help you get all instances of a class. This will thus return all defined classes

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class)
```

Comment: It will, however, also return classes that once were defined but aren't any longer, but haven't yet been garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `ObjectSpace`, a smart hook method you can define is `inherited`, which Ruby will invoke every time its class is subclassed.

```
class A
  @sub_classes = []

  def self.inherited(sub_class)
    @sub_classes << sub_class
  end
end
```